# Delay a Laravel Artisan command queued from code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-queue

I am running an Artisan command from a controller in my Laravel app. [As the docs specify](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code), you can queue like this:

```
Artisan::queue('email:send', [
    'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
]);
```

This takes care the queue logic and, in my case, sends the job off to Redis where it's processed almost immediately.

I want to delay the job. You [can normally do this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#delayed-jobs) when calling a queue command like so:

```
$job = (new SendReminderEmail($user))->delay(60);

$this->dispatch($job);
```

Is there a way to join these functions so I can delay my Artisan command for 5 minutes? I assumed there's be a simple option to delay it.

If not, I could create another Job class to stand between my controller and Artisan command, which I could queue in the normal way and delay, then have that Job call my Artisan command. But this seems like a really convoluted way to make  it work. Is there a better way to delay a queued Artisan command?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the console kernel uses "push" to queue a command, this is not possible for laravel 5.3 and earlier.

However you could make a pull request to the framework to implement the "later" call on the kernel, which could just pass through  to the queue´s "later" function.

Or just implement a job class, like you already stated.

But there is a better solution for your use case.
Just use the Mail facade:

```
Mail::later(5, 'emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
    //
});
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#queueing-mail for documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a custom email function as I need to use Mailgun API features that `Mail` can't handle, otherwise that would be a great way to do it! I went with the implement a job class way...

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the problem, using a scheduled task that is going to be watching for emails to send in the desired time. you can also use a table to set the email variables like the subject, template, template vars, time to send the email, etc.